# Is it possible to trigger Packer's post-processor skipping the build step?

Tags: vagrant, packer, post-processor

Let's asume I have a Packer file named `windows_10.json`. I ran `packer build windows_10.json` and it takes 3 to 4 hours to build a VirtualBox image of Windows 10. The build process finishes successfully and creates a VirtualBox image consisting of a `.ovf` and a `.vmdk` file compressed in a `.zip` file. Let's further asume that I have forgotten to add the code below for a vagrant post-processor to my `windows_10.json` file which should produce a Vagrant box:

`"post-processors": [
    {
      "type": "vagrant",
      "only": ["virtualbox-iso"],
      "keep_input_artifact": true,
      "output": "windows_10_{{.Provider}}.box",
      "vagrantfile_template": "vagrantfile-windows_10.template"
    }`

Now my question is: After adding the above code to `windows_10.json` file can I instruct Packer to do the post-process step ONLY and create a Vagrant box skipping the long build process? I don´t want to wait 3 to 4 hours again but instead continue with the creation of the Vagrant box.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you cannot skip the build process as some of the inputs it will use for the post processor will come from part of the builders steps.